# Fetch all users that meets the method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all the users where a given method in `User` model meets. Please see my code below:

`User.php`

```
public function isPicker(){
  return ($this->where('isPicker', 1)) ? true : false;
}
```

Now, I can use `User::all();`, but it returns all the users. What I want is to only return the users that meets the `isPicker()` method. What I'm trying to do in view is:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  @if($user->isPicker())
    {{ $user->first_name }}
  @endif
@endforeach
```

This is also working fine, but it is not that efficient to use. What if there's a lot of method to check? Any idea for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
$users = User::where('isPicker', 1)->get();
```

Or create a scope:

```
public function scopeIsPicker($query)
{
    return $query->where('isPicker', 1);
}

// usage
$users = User::isPicker()->get();
```

Comment: You add the function on the user model and laravel knows that since it starts with `scope` it can be called as `isPicker`. Here's the docs on the topic: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: Holy cow!  This is it. Didn't think it is available in laravel :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could change you code up a little to look like this.

```
@foreach($users->where('isPicker', 1)->all() as $user)
    {{ $user->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

But this will only work if the users var is a collection.

Other wise just change you query on how your getting the users to something like this.

```
User::where('isPicker', 1)->get()
```

Comment: You really should not run queries in your view files.

Comment: If I use `User::where('isPicker', 1)->get()`, what if in the future I added some methods that checks something for the `User` model?

Comment: Indeed. @DigitalDrifter is right. It will look messy if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in model file, you can directly query in your controller try below code

1. if you want to display only isPicker=1 users.

Controller Code :

```
$users = User::where('isPicker', 1)->get();
```

Blade code :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

OR

2. if you want to display all users including isPicker 0&1.

Controller Code :

```
$users = User::all();
```

Blade code :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  @if($user->isPicker == 1)
    {{ $user->first_name }}
  @else
    <p>Picker is 0</p>
  @endif  
@endforeach
```

Note : Remove your isPicker function from user model file because its unuse.